# How to create an JSON REST API kind of output using SQLite in Flutter?

Tags: mysql, flutter, sqlite

I have two tables,

`customers` table

```
+----+------------------+
| id | name             |
+----+------------------+
|  1 | Bhagwanti Nair   |
|  2 | Anuja Rana       |
|  3 | Mohana Varrier   |
|  4 | Trilochan Talwar |
|  5 | Charuvrat Gandhi |
+----+------------------+
```

`transactions` table

```
+----+----------+--------+
| id | customer | type   |
+----+----------+--------+
|  1 |        1 | debit  |
|  2 |        3 | debit  |
|  3 |        1 | credit |
|  4 |        4 | debit  |
|  5 |        1 | credit |
|  6 |        5 | credit |
|  7 |        3 | debit  |
|  8 |        4 | credit |
|  9 |        2 | credit |
| 10 |        2 | debit  |
+----+----------+--------+
```

I am building a Flutter app using the Sqlflite database. My aim is to write a query that outputs the following JSON result when I want to fetch `customers`:

```json
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Bhagwanti Nair",
    "transactions": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "customer": 1,
        "type": "debit"
      },
      {
        "id": 3,
        "customer": 1,
        "type": "credit"
      },
      {
        "id": 5,
        "customer": 1,
        "type": "credit"
      }
    ]
  },
  ... and so on
]
```

In the same way, I want to do for the `transactions`. It would be like:

```json
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "type": "debit",
    "customer": {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Bhagwanti Nair"
    }
  },
  ... and so on
]
```

The relation between `customers` and `transactions` tables is **one to many**.

My questions:

- Is it possible to do so in the **SQLite** database? If yes, then please help me out.
- If not, what is the best way to solve this issue?

Any help would be appreciated. Have a great day!

Answer (score 0):

If you can use SQLite's [JSON1 Extension](https://www.sqlite.org/json1.html) with Flutter, then you can aggregate with json's aggregate functions:

```
SELECT json_group_array(result) result
FROM (
  SELECT json_object(
           'id', c.id, 'name', c.name, 
           'transactions',  
           json_group_array(json_object('id', t.id, 'customer', t.customer, 'type', t.type))           
         ) result
  FROM customers c LEFT JOIN transactions t
  ON t.customer = c.id
  GROUP BY c.id
)
```

and:

```
SELECT json_array(
         json_object(
           'id', t.id, 'type', t.type, 
           'customer',  
           json_group_array(json_object('id', c.id, 'name', c.name))           
         )
       ) result
FROM transactions t INNER JOIN customers c
ON c.id = t.customer
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=0317708f5e5bc9e9b022ecd9251c7d96).

Comment: Hi @forpas. Is there a way to pick all fields instead of specifying them by name?

Comment: @RavgeetDhillon no there isn't. For each column you must hardcode its name.